# Devexpress Column Edit

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a column in my grid control which displays ID number that I retrieve from my database. For some reason, I need my column to always display only the last 6 digits in the ID number. Is that possible?

```
public CustomerCollection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.baseGridView = gridView1;
        base.baseUnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        base.baseXPCollectionEntity = xpCollectionEntity;
        ControlDefaultHelper.SetGridViewProperties(gridView1);
        ControlDefaultHelper.SetRepositoryItemCheckEditProperties(repositoryItemCheckEdit1);
    }

    public override void Edit(object entity)
    {
        base.Edit(entity);
        CustomerEdit modalForm = new CustomerEdit(entity as customer);
        modalForm.ShowDialog();
        RefreshData();
    }
```

All I did was choose my data source as seen below to retrieve data.

[image]

Comment: How many digit of your id now in current.. you can make it in a query if you want

Comment: i have up to 10,000,000

Comment: No im asking the field length not the record count.

Comment: @reds opps. sorry. 8 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it in a Query, Then Do it like this:

```
select SUBSTRING(field1 FROM 1 FOR 6)  from table1
```

then call it in your code..

sorry it last digit like this,

```
RIGHT(field1,6)
```

This is just an option

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work in my case because I'm using gridcontrol where all the details are retrieved straight from the database by selecting data source.

Comment: yeah but before that you are using query, ryt? so your query fill up the gridcontrol

Comment: check my edited post. that's all the code i have. it has no query in it.

Comment: ok seen it, you had a built in data source  and this is not a good practice i guess. You have to make your code or query become like dynamic. Hope you understand what i mean, Customize a result you want. im not a dev express expert but i tried to help you and find how to do it for you.

Comment: As ive search dev express connection pulling is the same with c#,

Comment: So it could be, i mean you can make a dynamic content of your gridcontrol

Comment: Welcome buddy.. just need to help you